Terminal onVscode
enter image description here
Please help me fix this terminal error because it looks very uncomfortable and hard to read. I have searched and have not found any effective way.
I help try reinstall and disable some extensions but it still not effective.

Go to settings > Search 'terminal font' > change your font.

I think it's a bug of vscode. Sometimes I get the same error as you. I click trash icon to delete terminal and open new terminal. It don't error anymore.
You can try my suggestion. I hope my suggestion will help you.

@user24349705 okay no problem, remember vote me best answer. Have a nice day!
